# How to use MemoryMappedViewAccessor of shared memory function in C#

Tags: c#, shared-memory

I reference to the msdn [share memory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267552(v=vs.110).aspx)

and find the CreateViewStream, now I want create int

in memory use MemoryMappedViewAccessor

```
// Process A:
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("testmap", 10000))
        {
        bool mutexCreated;
        Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "testmapmutex", out mutexCreated);
        using (MemoryMappedViewStream stream = mmf.CreateViewStream())
        {
            BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
            writer.Write(1);
        }
        mutex.ReleaseMutex();

        // Read Int 
        MemoryMappedViewAccessor accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor();
        // For Process B Read
        accessor.Write(499, 41);
        // For Process B Read
        accessor.Write(500, 42);
        // For Process C Read
        accessor.Write(501, 43);
        accessor.Dispose();

        Console.WriteLine("Start Process B and press ENTER to continue.");
        Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Start Process C and press ENTER to continue.");
        Console.ReadLine();

        mutex.WaitOne();
        using (MemoryMappedViewStream stream = mmf.CreateViewStream())
        {
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
            MemoryMappedViewAccessor access = mmf.CreateViewAccessor();
            Console.WriteLine("Process A says: {0} ", reader.ReadBoolean());
            Console.WriteLine("Process B says: {0} ", reader.ReadBoolean());
            Console.WriteLine("Process C says: {0} ", reader.ReadBoolean());

            Console.WriteLine("Process A Int:{0}", access.ReadInt32(499));
            Console.WriteLine("Process B Int:{0}", access.ReadInt32(500));
            Console.WriteLine("Process C Int:{0}", access.ReadInt32(501));
            access.Dispose();
        }
        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        mmf.Dispose();
    }
    Console.Read();
}
```

but the result is as follow

> Process A says: True
>       Process B says: False
>       Process C says: False
>       Process A Int:2828841
>       Process B Int:11050
>       Process C Int:43

Anyone can tell me the problem?

why the result Process A、B

is not 41 and 42

Comment: They are 41 and 42, it is just not that easy to see when you use the wrong method to read them.  Use ReadByte() instead.  Or to put it another way, you did not create ints in the mmf.  An int needs 4 bytes for storage, so you need to write to 499, 499+4=503, 503+4=507.

Comment: ok, it work well for fixed the ReadInt32 to ReadByte or 500 -> 503 501 -> 507, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chage this code

```
// For Process B Read
accessor.Write(499, 41);
// For Process B Read
accessor.Write(503, 42);
// For Process C Read
accessor.Write(507, 43);
Console.WriteLine("Process A Int:{0}", access.ReadInt32(499));
Console.WriteLine("Process B Int:{0}", access.ReadInt32(503));
Console.WriteLine("Process C Int:{0}", access.ReadInt32(507));
```

then the result is

Process A Int:41
Process B Int:42
Process C Int:43

or chage this code

```
Console.WriteLine("Process A Int:{0}", access.ReadByte(499));
Console.WriteLine("Process B Int:{0}", access.ReadByte(500));
Console.WriteLine("Process C Int:{0}", access.ReadByte(501));
```

have same result

thanks for @Hans Passant